# Tax4fun R software error ; Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am using a software called Tax4fun in r software. I use the following commands

```
#Load the package
library(Tax4Fun)
#Import the data
data=importQIIMEData("table.from_biom_w_taxonomy.txt")

#Run command

Tax4FunOutput=Tax4Fun(QiimeData,"SILVA123" , fctProfiling = FALSE,
                  refProfile = "UProC", shortReadMode = FALSE, normCopyNo = TRUE)
```

All the commands run well apart from the last one which bring the following error

> Error in dimnames(x)<-dn:length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

I am not sure what the error mean
Any assistance will be highly appreciated